# Android potential deadlock analyzing

Tags: android, performance, deadlock

I have really big and old project, and i need to analyze it for potential deadlocks. Doing this task by hands will take a lot of time, and I'm trying to find anything useful for find potential deadlocks in the code.
Have anybody this experience? With what tools, tutorials?

I'm tried FindBugs, but it doesn't provide any info about potential deadlocks.

Comment: No experience myself but came across this [Debugging](https://quequero.org/2012/01/debugging-deadlocks-on-android/) & another [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499634/how-to-detect-and-debug-multi-threading-problems) where someone talks about a tool [ThreadSafe](http://www.contemplateltd.com/threadsafe).

Comment: Yeah, but ThreadSafe is java tool, not android. ThreadSafe using his own virtual machine, and in this case we can't use it for android.