# Debuging multiple threads in asp.net mvc 5 controller method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

I'm working on a project(ASP.NET MVC 5) that may have some race hazards when it comes to its business logic, specifically what happens when two users call the same controller method in approximately same time.

So i decided to test this by setting up a breakpoint in the aforementioned controller method, and then i try hit that breakpoint by sending a request from my browser. Then i open up a new tab and try to load my website again, but the problem is it's not loading.

Website is completely(all pages) unresponsive until i release the breakpoint.

In threads window i can see that there are few worker threads that are unassigned and that one single thread that is stuck at the breakpoint.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 community.

Is this behavior normal? If that's the case how should i approach my problem?

Comment: Debugging will lock all threads until the break is released. Or else how would you debug anything?

Comment: it will stuck at your breakpoint untill you release and IIS(in reality site) will take those two request different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect and debug multi-threading problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499634/how-to-detect-and-debug-multi-threading-problems)

Comment: @Liam i am still not very familiar with multithreading in c# applications but i am certain that in java(eclipse) only the thread that hits the breakpoint is the one that is stopped(others continue running). I  assumed it was similar here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mis-understanding how debugging works here. Visual studio is doing exactly what it's supposed to. It's stopping all execution on your breakpoint until you release it. In a real production environment, or while debugging without a breakpoint, you will see that it will return to both at the same time (as far as you could tell unless you're some extremely long running operation, in which case you should be using async/await).

In reality it (IIS) will queue the requests and process them .

Comment: So IIS will not assign tasks to other worker threads until i am finished debugging my one thread if i understood correctly? If it only queues the requests, that is a bummer.

Comment: The debugger is attached to the worker process (w3wp). The worker process manages the threads. VS haults the worker process (and all the threads) when a breakpoint is hit. IIS uses the worker process to perform all server side calculations. It's actually more to do with .Net than IIS.

Comment: Race conditions are hard to detect. BTW if your not using a shared resource then it's not going to be a race condition