# Part of the Stacktrace is misssing in Exception, while registering Path with WatchService for non existing file

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace, watchservice

The below code is to register a (non existing) Path for watching the `create` file system event.

I see some details are missing in the stack trace.

```
public final class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
  {
    Path path = Paths.get("NonExistentFile.txt");
    WatchService watchService = path.getFileSystem().newWatchService();

    try
    {
      register(true, path, watchService);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.err.println();

    try
    {
      WatchKey watchKey = register(false, path, watchService);
      watchKey.cancel();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  static WatchKey register(boolean exception, Path path, WatchService watchService) throws IOException
  {
    if (exception)
      throw new RuntimeException("Test Runtime Exception");
    return path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
  }
}
```

Exceptions stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Runtime Exception
  at test.Test.register(Test.java:44)
  at test.Test.main(Test.java:20)

java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: NonExistentFile.txt
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.asIOException(UnixException.java:111)
  at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.implRegister(LinuxWatchService.java:246)
  at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.processRequests(AbstractPoller.java:260)
  at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:329)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Question: Why is `test.Test.register/main` is missing in the second stack trace?

Comment: Because the second stack is from a different thread generated by WatchService.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is test.Test.register/main is missing in the second stack trace?

Basically, there are two threads running in the program, one is the `main` thread and the other one for `nio` file handling. JVM stacktrace is individual to each thread which depends upon the methods (stack) the thread is involved with. **So, you are getting the exception stacktrace individually for each thread.**

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) for more details on understanding stacktrace.

You can replicate the same thing with a simple example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         new Thread(() -> {
                 throw new RuntimeException("My Exception 
        Message from child Thread **");
         }).start();

         throw new RuntimeException("My Exception  Message 
             from main Thread ** ");
     }
```

**Output:**

```
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
   My Exception  Message from child Thread **
    at com.Testing.lambda$0(Testing.java:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.RuntimeException: My Exception  Message from main Thread **
    at com.myproject.samples.Testing.main(Testing.java:16)
```

> In your example exception is not killing the main thread, but in my case it does ?

My main thread is not dependent upon the result of the child thread, whereas yours it does.

> How is one supposed to debug the problem, if the application crashes and there is no (proper) stack trace (in other words is this
>   not a bug)?

JVM stacktrace is individual to each thread which depends upon the methods (stack) the thread is involved with. It is the same issue with any multithreaded application. You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499634/how-to-detect-and-debug-multi-threading-problems) on details for debugging multithreaded code.

Comment: Two questions 1. In your example exception is not killing the main thread, but in my case it does. 2. How is one supposed to debug the problem, if the application crashes and there is no (proper) stack trace (in other words is this not a bug)?

Comment: (1) My main thread is not dependent upon the result of the child thread, whereas yours it does. (2) JVM stacktrace is individual to each thread which depends upon the methods (stack) the thread is involved with. It is the same issue with any multithreaded application.

Comment: Updated my answer as well, you can have a look