# Getting wrong result after Subtracting a day from a date Using LocalDateTIme and ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, dst, java-time, zoneddatetime

I am testing with `"2016-03-28T02:00:00+0200"` (1459123200 in UTC Sec.)

After subtracting 1 day, DST is applied and output should be:

> "2016-03-27T03:00:00+0200"

But I am getting this:

> 2016-03-26T01:00+01:00[Europe/Stockholm]

CODE:

```
public class DateFormatSampleCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(1459123200, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);

        System.out.println(localDateTime);
        localDateTime = localDateTime.minusDays(1);
        System.out.println(localDateTime);

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("Europe/Stockholm"));

        System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
    }
}
```

Please check and point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: You can't subtract a day from a *local* date/time, which has no notion of daylight savings, and expect it to apply daylight saving rules.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Could you suggest how to get it done.

Comment: If you want zoned date/times, used ZonedDateTime. Don't use `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: I think i have already used it above. The thing is i am getting time in sec. in UTC format from epoch. I need to store it and return with zoned offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can answer my above question.

Here is the code.

```
public ZonedDateTime addDays(long myUTCTimeInSeconds, int days) {
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(myUTCTimeInSeconds);
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeWithOffSet = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    if (localDays >= 0) {
        dateTimeWithOffSet = dateTimeWithOffSet.plusDays(localDays);
    } else {
        dateTimeWithOffSet = dateTimeWithOffSet.minusDays(abs(localDays));
    }
    return dateTimeWithOffSet;
}
```

If the timezone is different from that of system, we can set the Default TimeZone and after calling above method reset the timezone as:

```
TimeZone systemDefaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));

addDays(1459123200, 1);
TimeZone.setDefault(systemDefaultTimeZone);
```

Answer (score 2):

Good you found a solution, I'd just like to add some insights and suggest a little improvement to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42641012/7605325).

Setting the JVM default timezone using `TimeZone.setDefault` is not the best way to achieve this. Although it might work for most times, it's a little risky and error prone if you consider this code running in a more complex environment.

That's because `TimeZone.setDefault` changes the default timezone for the **whole** JVM. Any other application running in the same JVM will be affected by it. Other parts of the same application will also be affected, and even this same code running in multiple threads might give you wrong results (and [race conditions are hard to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/499659/7605325)).

I noticed that you're using `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezone));`. This means that you are  already working with a specific timezone, so there's no need to rely on the JVM's default. If you have a specific timezone name, just use it instead of the default. So I suggest you that the `addDays` method should be like this:

```
public ZonedDateTime addDays(long myUTCTimeInSeconds, int days, String timezone) {
    // get the instant from the UTC seconds
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(myUTCTimeInSeconds);
    // get the instant at the specified timezone
    ZonedDateTime z = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of(timezone));

    // add days
    return z.plusDays(days);
}
```

The improvements made:

- `plusDays` already subtracts 1 day if you pass `-1` to it. There's no need to check the value and use `abs` method.
- don't use the JVM default timezone: instead of `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, use the `timezone` that you already have (the one you were using in the `setDefault` method)
- `instant.atZone` is equivalent to `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant`. IMO, `atZone` is more "readable", but in this case it's a matter of choice and code-style. It doesn't make difference in the final result.

With this, you could do:

```
// call directly, no need to change the default timezone
System.out.println(addDays(1459123200, -1, "Europe/Stockholm"));
```

This will print:

> 2016-03-27T03:00+02:00[Europe/Stockholm]